# Strange Load behavior with Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox

Tags: javascript, rally

Sorry if this has been covered before - but I'm experiencing some weird load behavior with the Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox.

All the app does (so far) is this:

1. Create a Rally.ui.combobox.IterationComboBox
2. Once an iteration is Selected, Populate a Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox using a UserStory    model filtered to the Selected Iteration.

I'm seeing some strange behavior when clicking on the UserStory combobox. It initially shows only a handful of stories (correctly, those that are within the Selected Iteration.

However, after a moment or two it re-draws itself and then displays all the Stories in my Project.

The JS console shows a handful of these errors:

- `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getCount' of null`
- `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loading' of null`

I suspect I'm doing something wrong with the timing of when the Story Combobox is ready. So I added an onReady handler, but it doesn't seem to be doing much to help.

A video of the behavior is here:

- http://screencast.com/t/LxoX9qLD

And my code is shown here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CustomApp</title>
    <!--  (c) 2013 Rally Software Development Corp.  All Rights Reserved. -->
    <!--  Build Date: Mon Jul 15 2013 14:23:12 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {

            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

                // Stores the Selected Iteration
                selectedIteration: null,

                // Data Store for Stories
                storyStore: null,

                // Stores the Selected Story
                selectedStory: null,

                // Reference to lumenize
                lumenize: null,

                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        itemId: 'iterationDropdownContainer',
                        columnWidth: 1
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        itemId: 'storyDropdownContainer',
                        columnWidth: 1
                    },      
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        itemId: 'testResultSummaryContainer',
                        columnWidth: 1
                    }    
                ],

                launch: function() {
                    // Add the iteration dropdown selector
                    this.down("#iterationDropdownContainer").add( {
                        xtype: 'rallyiterationcombobox',
                        itemId : 'iterationSelector',
                        listeners: {
                            select: this._onIterationSelect,
                            scope: this
                        }
                    });

                    // Lumenize
                    this.lumenize = window.parent.Rally.data.lookback.Lumenize; 
                },

                // Callback when an iteration is selected.
                _onIterationSelect : function() {
                    // Store and save the Selected Iteration        
                    var iterationRecord =  this.down('#iterationSelector').getRecord();
                    this.selectedIteration = iterationRecord.data;
                    console.log(iterationRecord);               

                    // Query to get all Stories in Iteration
                    this.storyStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                        model: "User Story",
                        autoLoad: true,
                        fetch: ["ObjectID","Name","Iteration","TestCases"],
                        filters: [
                            {
                                property: 'Iteration.Name',
                                value: this.selectedIteration.Name
                            }
                        ],
                        listeners: {
                            scope : this,
                            load : this._storiesLoaded
                        }
                    }); 
                },

                // Callback when Story Store is loaded
                _storiesLoaded : function(store, data, success) {
                    console.log("_storiesLoaded");
                    console.log(data);

                    if(this.down("#storySelector")) {
                        this.down("#storySelector").destroy();
                    }

                    // Add a story object dropdown selector 
                    this.down("#storyDropdownContainer").add( {
                        xtype: 'rallycombobox',
                        store: this.storyStore,
                        autoLoad: false,
                        disabled: true,
                        itemId : 'storySelector',
                        listeners: {
                            ready: this._storySelectorReady,
                            select: this._onStorySelected,
                            scope: this
                        }
                    }); 
                },

                _storySelectorReady: function(storyCombobox) {
                    storyCombobox.disabled = false;
                },    

                // Callback when a Story has been selected
                _onStorySelected : function() {
                    // Store and save the Selected Iteration        
                    var storyRecord =  this.down('#storySelector').getRecord();
                    this.selectedStory = storyRecord.data;

                    console.log(storyRecord);
                },    

                _showTable : function() {
                    console.log("_showTable");
                }            
            });

           Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
               name: 'CustomApp'
           });
        });
    </script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/style/app.css">

</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storyStore is loading twice, once when you created it, and the combobox also tells it to load again once the user opens the combobox to pick a story. So your load listener for the store is getting called twice, and actually two story comboboxes are getting created. Somewhere deep inside Ext, it's not liking this.

The simplest fix is to add `single: true` to your store's listener:

```
listeners: {
    scope : this,
    load : this._storiesLoaded,
    single: true
}
```

But probably a better approach is to setup the store as part of creating the story combobox:

```
_onIterationSelect : function() {
  // Store and save the Selected Iteration        
  var iterationRecord =  this.down('#iterationSelector').getRecord();
  this.selectedIteration = iterationRecord.data;
  console.log(iterationRecord);               

  this.down("#storyDropdownContainer").add( {
        xtype: 'rallycombobox',
        itemId : 'storySelector',
        storeConfig: {
            model: 'User Story',
            autoLoad: true,
            filters: [{
                  property: 'Iteration.Name',
                  value: this.selectedIteration.Name
            }]
        },
        listeners: {
             ready: this._storySelectorReady,
             select: this._onStorySelected,
             scope: this
        }
  }); 
},
```

Comment: Mystery solved, many thanks Matt! Is it standard best practice with SDK2 to instantiate the store in concert with newing up the component, as opposed to passing in the store as I had done?