# Rally App SDK 2.0rc1 - Why does my combobox ignore datastore filters only on first click?

Tags: javascript, combobox, rally

I have the following code (sloppy, I know...first javascript app). I am trying to get a combobox to populate with a list of features that fall under a given release (as selected in the first combobox). Almost everything is now working correctly, *except* everytime I click the feature combobox for the first time, it loads ALL features and completely ignores the filter. Even if I change the release box first, the feature box still populates with all features only on first click. Subsequent times it shows the correctly filtered features.

Even stranger, I've tried writing the total records in the Feature Store to the console, so I can see when this happens. When the feature combobox is first created, it has the correct number of records in it. However, as soon as I click the feature combobox for the first time, it triggers the "load" listener of the combobox, and pulls in all the features, ignoring the filter completely.

I'm so boggled, I've tried so many things to debug this, and at this point have no other options. Does anyone have any ideas as to why it would load the correct data first, then reload it and ignore the filters on first click?

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',

launch: function() {

    var relComboBox = Ext.create("Rally.ui.combobox.ReleaseComboBox", {
        fieldLabel: 'Choose a Release',
        width: 300,
        listeners: {
            ready: function(combobox) {
                this._releaseRef = combobox.getRecord().get("_ref");
                this._loadFeatureInfo();
            },
            select: function(combobox) {
                this._releaseRef = combobox.getRecord().get("_ref");
                this._loadFeatureInfo();
            },
            scope: this
        }
    });

    this.add(relComboBox);
},
_loadFeatureInfo: function() {
    var featureStore = Ext.create("Rally.data.WsapiDataStore", {
        model: "portfolioitem/Feature",
        fetch: ["Name", "_ref"],
        autoLoad: true,
        filters: [
            {
                property: "Release",
                operator: "=",
                value: this._releaseRef
            }
        ],
        listeners: {
            load: function(store) {
                this._updateFeatureBox(store);
            },
            scope: this
        }
    });
},
_createFeatureBox: function(featureStore) {
    this._featureComboBox = Ext.create("Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox", {
        fieldLabel: 'Choose a Feature to move',
        store: featureStore,
        listeners: {
            select: function (combobox) {
                this._featureRef = combobox.getRecord().get("_ref");
                //calls method to get and display children of this feature in a grid
            },
            scope: this
        }
    });
    this.add(this._featureComboBox);
},
_updateFeatureBox: function(featureStore) {
    if (this._featureComboBox === undefined) {
        this._createFeatureBox(featureStore);
    } else {
        this._featureComboBox.clearValue();
        this._featureComboBox.bindStore(featureStore);
        //calls method to get and display children of this feature in a grid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably an issue caused by the featureStore loading twice: once when you created it, and the combobox also tells it to load again once the user opens the combobox to pick a Feature.

I encountered a very similar issue with a combobox on Stories, and I'd betcha dollars to donuts that [Matt Greer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194940/matt-greer)'s answer:

[Strange Load behavior with Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663475/strange-load-behavior-with-rally-ui-combobox-combobox)

To my question, is the answer to yours too...

Comment: This was indeed my problem! The "easy fix" (single: true) didn't work for me :(. However, refactoring to pass the combobox a storeConfig on creation did work.